# How can I stop Clang from overexpanding nested loops via templates?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-optimization, template-meta-programming, loop-unrolling

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef long xint;
template<int N>
struct foz {
    template<int i=0>
    static void foo(xint t) {
        for (int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
            foo<i+1> (t+j);
        }
    }
    template<>
    static void foo<N>(xint t) {
        std::cout << t;
    }

};

int main() {
    foz<8>::foo<0>(0);
}
```

When compiling in `clang++ -O0`, it compiles in seconds and then run for 4 seconds.

However, with `clang++ -O2`, compiling takes a long time and lots of memory. On [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:24,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:24,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:24,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:24,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Atypedef+long+xint%3B%0Atemplate%3Cint+N%3E%0Astruct+foz+%7B%0A++++template%3Cint+i%3D0%3E%0A++++static+void+foo(xint+t)+%7B%0A++++++++for+(int+j%3D0%3B+j%3C10%3B+%2B%2Bj)+%7B%0A++++++++++++foo%3Ci%2B1%3E+(t%2Bj)%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++++template%3C%3E%0A++++static+void+foo%3CN%3E(xint+t)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+t%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++foz%3C4%3E::foo%3C0%3E(0)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.681842026061446,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:42,endLineNumber:36,positionColumn:42,positionLineNumber:36,selectionStartColumn:42,selectionStartLineNumber:36,startColumn:42,startLineNumber:36),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.318157973938554,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), it can be seen that, with `8` changed to smaller value, it fully expands the loop.

I'm not making it fully no optimization, but to make it not recursive, just like what a nested loop should behave like. Is there anything I should do?

Comment: Might be worth submitting a bug report, clearly some inlining heuristics should be tweaked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Loop unrolling optimization can be disabled; see on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:10,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:9,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:10,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Atypedef+long+xint%3B%0Atemplate%3Cint+N%3E%0Astruct+foz+%7B%0A++++template%3Cint+i%3D0%3E%0A++++static+void+foo(xint+t)+%7B%0A++++++++%23pragma+nounroll%0A++++++++for+(int+j%3D0%3B+j%3C10%3B+%2B%2Bj)+%7B%0A++++++++++++foo%3Ci%2B1%3E+(t%2Bj)%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++++template%3C%3E%0A++++static+void+foo%3CN%3E(xint+t)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+t%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++foz%3C4%3E::foo%3C0%3E(0)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.681842026061446,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.318157973938554,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) . The produced code is non-recursive and expressed in terms of nested loops.

```
#pragma nounroll
for (int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
    foo<i+1> (t+j);
}
```

Also you can manually tune unrolling instead of disabling it. Unrolling by 8 generates similar code to the one that is looping 8 times. ([Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:10,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:10,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:10,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:10,startLineNumber:10),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0Atypedef+long+xint%3B%0Atemplate%3Cint+N%3E%0Astruct+foz+%7B%0A++++template%3Cint+i%3D0%3E%0A++++static+void+foo(xint+t)+%7B%0A++++++++%23pragma+unroll+8%0A++++++++for+(int+j%3D0%3B+j%3C10%3B+%2B%2Bj)+%7B%0A++++++++++++foo%3Ci%2B1%3E+(t%2Bj)%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++++template%3C%3E%0A++++static+void+foo%3CN%3E(xint+t)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+t%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++foz%3C4%3E::foo%3C0%3E(0)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.681842026061446,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.318157973938554,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

```
#pragma unroll 8
for (int j=0; j<10; ++j) {
    foo<i+1> (t+j);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it non-recursive, you might use array as indexes:

```
static bool increase(std::array<int, N>& a)
{
    for (auto rit = std::rbegin(a); rit != std::rend(a); ++rit) {
        if (++*rit == 10) {
            *rit = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static void foo(xint t) {
    std::array<int, N> indexes{};

    do {
        std::cout << std::accumulate(std::begin(indexes), std::end(indexes), 0);
    } while (increase(indexes));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dWhdMdvMe)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to mark the problematic function using the [`noinline` function attribute](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#noinline), which is also supported by several other C++ compilers (e.g. [GNU g++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)):

```cpp
    template<int i=0>
    static void foo(xint t)  __attribute__((__noinline__)) {
```

This instructs the compiler's optimizer to never inline calls to that function.

Comment: `noinline` preserves recursion, while I'd prefer nested loop